# String Variable in Visual Studio 2008 Expression Expected

Tags: string, variables, visual-studio-2008

```
Dim Html As String
        Html = '<head> ' $_
        '<title>Send SMS</title>' $_
'</head>'
```

I am having error that at line 2 Expression needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes to enclose strings.  Use ampersands for concatenation.  Like so:

```
    Dim Html As String
    Html = "<head> " & _
    "<title>Send SMS</title>" & _
    "</head>"
```